# Debugging with Debugger not working in Julia when using Juno / Atom

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I'm trying to step through a function in Julia when using the Juno IDE (i.e., Atom with the Julia extension). I'm using Julia 1.1 and the Debugger package.

I'm trying to enter the function as follows:

```
@enter myfunc(5)
```

And when I run this, it opens the REPL to the correct function in debug mode, but when I try to press `c` or `n` to continue or run to the next function I get the following:

`no previous command executed`

Also, when I press ` (backtick) to enter interactive mode, it doesn't really work and creates some weird behavior that's hard to succinctly describe.

What does this error mean, and how do I get simple debugging to work in Juno?

Atom version: 1.36
OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `CTRL+ENTER` to run this command, which for some reason (unknown to me) creates this weird behavior in Juno. If you copy the line of code with `@enter` or `@run`, and paste it directly in the REPL yourself, you should find the debugging working properly. I have been using it successfully that way.

Comment: This is fixed in the latest version of Juno (0.12).