# With Julia's Debugger.jl - How can I enter debug mode similar to Python's pdb.set_trace() or ipdb.set_trace()?

Tags: debugging, julia

Julia's new Debugger.jl is great, but it's kind of a pain to get to the exact point in code that I want to get to sometimes.

Is there a way I can enter an interactive debug mode, similar to what Python has in pdb.set_trace() or ipdb.set_trace()? For example, I'd love to be able to insert a line of code where I want the debugger to start, like so:

```
function myfunc(a, b)
     # do stuff
     set_trace() # interactive debug mode will start here
     # do other stuff
end
```

p.s. I know that this is basically like setting a breakpoint in Juno, but 1) I can't always develop in Juno; and 2) I couldn't really get breakpoints to work well with Juno's debugger even after a lot of struggling. It might be my user error but I'm sure other Julia newbies will encounter the same problems and would love a solution like pdb.set_trace().

Answer (score 5):

The function you're looking for is wonderfully concise:

```
@bp
```

Just make sure you have loaded the Debugger package so that you can use it:

```
using Debugger
```

Note that it won't actually stop at the breakpoint if you run the outer-most function (e.g., myfunc) via normal methods. You need to run it in debug mode using `@enter` or `@run`. Here's a complete example:

```
using Debugger
function myfunc(a, b)
     c = a + b
     @bp # interactive debug mode will start here
     c += 1
end

@run myfunc(42, 5)
```

(Juno [sometimes produces weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228328/debugging-with-debugger-not-working-in-julia-when-using-juno-atom/56228329#56228329) when you run the `@run ...` line using CTRL+ENTER. It may be better to copy and paste that particular line directly into the REPL instead.)

`@bp` is actually a macro that's part of JuliaInterpreter.jl. That module has many other useful functions for debugging - see [the JuliaInterpreter docs](https://juliadebug.github.io/JuliaInterpreter.jl/latest/dev_reference/#JuliaInterpreter.@bp) for more details.

Comment: Why does @bp not work in global scope????