# Equivalent of import pdb; pdb.set_trace() in Julia

Tags: julia

Before you suggest Debugger.jl: [With Julia's Debugger.jl - How can I enter debug mode similar to Python's pdb.set_trace() or ipdb.set_trace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229927/with-julias-debugger-jl-how-can-i-enter-debug-mode-similar-to-pythons-pdb-se)

It does NOT work in the global scope. The @bp macro seems to only work inside a function, else it does nothing.

In Python, you can place import pdb; pdb.set_trace() anywhere and it brings up a debugger. What is the equivalent in Julia?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Infiltrator.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Infiltrator.jl).

You can put `@infiltrate` in global scope. Note though that then `@trace` and `@locals` will be empty (but you can inspect state of global variables by just checking them).